# Automatic value through Javascript or Controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, .net, model-view-controller

Trying to figure out the best way to update a database value, based on a textbox value. The database has a value "Amount Added" and then also "Money". The "Money" column is the cost, which is dependent upon the Ammount Added value.

What I want is to either automatically update a textbox for "Money" after the value in "Ammount Added" is updated, or, for the controller to do the maths and input the value after clicking submit.

I've tried doing it through JavaScript (Really not my strong point), which I've done this way, found on another post here.

```
    $(document).ready(function Update() {
    var one = document.GetElementById('AmountAdded'),
        two = document.GetElementById('Money');

    two.value = parseInt(one.value) * 2 / 100;
})
```

That hasn't worked, but am I on the right track with it, and would it be the best way to do it? Or should I be looking at doing it through the controller?

If it makes any sort of difference, I'm using Entity Framework

UPDATE
I moved the JavaScript to Layout page after realising it was in the body due to being in the view (if that makes sense)?, and on recommendation from Dhaval, changed the "GetElementById" to "getElementById".

First reload set the "Money" value to NaN, so I then set the default value to 0, but changing that after doesn't change the value in the Html.EditorFor.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI: `GetElementById()` and `getElementById()` are different in javascript!

Comment: Beyond that, is the JavaScript right? Not my strong point, and I struggle to understand it. From what I can make out as well, "@onchange" may not work an editorfor in Razor?

Comment: @ChrisBarsby, I have updated my answer responding to your comment for change events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        Update();

        $('#AmountAdded, #Money')
            .change(function(){
                Update();
         });
    }
);

function Update() {
    var one = $('#AmountAdded'),
    two = $('#Money');

    two.val(parseInt(one.val()) * 2 / 100);
}
```

Comment: Have done so, however, what would I put into the onChange event for the Editor.For, as I can't see an identifier of any sort in there or would the JavaScript run regardless?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using jquery, you can try below codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#AmountAdded').on('change',function(){
        var cost = $('#AmountAdded').val() * 2 / 100;
        $('#Money').val(cost);
    })
})
```